# I want to optimize this query , created new table with subquery select it's fine but problem is that query run take time 30 minutes

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, laravel

I want to optimize this query.
Query takes way too long (30 min)

```
Create Table newtable
Select start_date, CAST(odo_meter AS UNSIGNED) current_odo, 
CAST(odo_meter AS UNSIGNED) - ifnull((Select odo_meter from customer_transactions_dashboard custtrans where custmain.start_date > custtrans.start_date
and CAST(odo_meter AS UNSIGNED) > 0 and custmain.site_id = custtrans.site_id and
custmain.vehicle_id = custtrans.vehicle_id order by custtrans.start_date asc limit 1),CAST(odo_meter AS UNSIGNED)) KmTraveled,
custmain.total_cost current_cost,
custmain.litres current_litre,
(Select sum(total_cost) from customer_transactions_dashboard custtrans where custmain.start_date > custtrans.start_date
and CAST(odo_meter AS UNSIGNED) > 0 and custmain.site_id = custtrans.site_id and
custmain.vehicle_id = custtrans.vehicle_id) `total_cost`,
(Select sum(litres) from customer_transactions_dashboard custtrans where custmain.start_date > custtrans.start_date
and CAST(odo_meter AS UNSIGNED) > 0 and custmain.site_id = custtrans.site_id and
custmain.vehicle_id = custtrans.vehicle_id) `total_liter`,
custmain.site_id, custmain.vehicle_id
from customer_transactions_dashboard custmain;
```

Comment: Start with an online query formatter. Then see EXPLAIN.

Comment: plz check this is complete query

Answer (score 0):

Instead of repeat the select for each rows  and column  you could use  a join with the group by  for site and vehicle

```
select  c.start_date
  , CAST(c.odo_meter AS UNSIGNED) current_odo - ifnull(t.odo_meter, c.odo_meter
  , c.total_cost current_cost
  , c.litres current_litre
  , t.total_cost
  , t.total_liter
from  customer_transactions_dashboard c
INNER JOIN  (
    select  site_id
        , vehicle_id
        , odo_meter
        , sum(total_cost) `total_cost`
        , sum(litres) `total_liter`
    from customer_transactions_dashboard
    where custmain.start_date > custtrans.start_date
    and CAST(odo_meter AS UNSIGNED) > 0 
    group by  site_id, vehicle_id
) t on t.site_id = c.site_id 
    and t.vehicle_id = c.vehicle_id
```

be sure you have  proper index  on  table customer_transactions_dashboard column  site_id,  vehicle_id
and a second index  on the same table for  column start_date